# Ignore $strLenBytes if field doesn't exist or use substitution in MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to do a simple "data quality check" within data stored in a MongoDB collection. One important part of "quality" is the length of text stored in a specific field (`description`).

To get the length I'm aggregating it with `$strLenBytes`. This works fine unless a document is missing the field in question. Then I get *"$strLenBytes requires a string argument, found: missing".* I can't exclude documents without that field and would rather get a length of 0 or null or something like that instead. Hence I need something to "replace" or dynamically generate that field in case it doesn't exist in a document.

The query looks something like this (the field is `description`):

```
$cursor = $MongoDB->someCollection->aggregate([
    ['$match' => [
            'client_id' => 12345
        ]
    ],
    ['$project' => [
            'desc_length' => [
                '$strLenBytes' => '$description'
            ],
            'client_id' => true
        ]
    ],
    ['$limit' => 10]
    ]);
```

So is there a possibility to "inject" an empty field `description` if it doesn't exist? Or to aggregate `desc_length` only, if `description` exist? Well, skipping the generation of `desc_length` wouldn't be preferable since it's part of the "quality" and I'd like to sort later by a generated quality value. Anyway, I could do that on php's side, too, if necessary.

Comment: It's not the job of the aggregation framework or MongoDB to do this. Instead it's up to **your code**, which should instead check the attached MongoDB server version and then issue commands appropriately. Therefore you would not send a pipeline with operators that depended on MongoDB 3.4 when the detected server version was lower than that version. A bit broad as a general statement, because not all operators are "replacable" by something else. `$strLenBytes` for instance has no alternate approach in the aggregation framework, so there is no other operation you could use as a substitute.

Comment: Sorry for wrong formulation. I don't want to substitute $strLenBytes. I am using MongoDB 3.4. I want to substitute the missing field.

Comment: [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/), That's what it is there for.

Comment: Thank you Neil, that does the trick. `'desc_length' => ['$strLenBytes' => ['$ifNull' => [ '$description', 'a' ]]]`